# android Traceviewer

Tags: android, trace

I am Trying to use trace viewer by

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("sampletrace");

Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

And I pull the `sampletrace` to a folder from sdcard.

When I try to view the tracefile using the following command.

```
D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>traceview D:\trace\sampletrace.trace
```

it is showing the following line

```
Key section does not have an *end marker
```

Can anybody please explain what is this?

Answer (score 3):

in your eclipse file-explorer window, in sdcard your traceview file size is 0 because
you can not properly call Debug.stopMethodTracing() method in your code.
you have to call it when you are finished your application.
when you finished your application in emulator your traceview file size is now not a 0(zero).
now execute your next step as describe in api.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call a corresponding Debug.stopMethodTracing(). Without this call the trace is incomplete and you'll see this marker error when you try to load it in the traceviewer